# Physical properties of the phone

Tags: android

Does android have a class which have saved weight(mass) of the phone? ( or is any way to get a weight of the phone)

I'm creating an app where I need to know mass of the phone so that I will be able to use some physical formulas.

*If there isn't any way* (I doubt about it) could someone tell me a standard approximation

Comment: You can scrap any website which have information about that phone and save it to your db.

Comment: I think there is no such information stored in your phone. And I'm sure there is no standard approximation. As mentionned by Sunny, find a website that will give you the mass of your specific phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way using Android API to find it out.
But you can get the model of device using the following:

```
Log.i("TAG","MODEL: " + Build.MODEL);
```

And then maybe find an API in which you can scrape data for mass (gram).
For example this site looks suitable for it:
http://phonedb.net/

But a fair warning, if you're planning to make an commercial app, it's best you find an official way and contact the website that you're scraping data from it.

Comment: Thanks, it's not commercial app so it should be fine.